# ansible use tags but register variable is empty

Tags: ansible, tags

I want to execute a playbook with tags, because I want to execute part of script, but the variable stored in register is empty.

```
---
- hosts: node
  vars:
    service_name: apache2
  become: true

- name: Start if Service Apache is stopped
  shell: service apache2 status | grep Active | awk -v N=2 '{print $N}'
  args:
    warn: false
  register: res
  tags:
    - toto

- name: Start Apache because service was stopped
  service:
    name: "{{service_name}}"
    state: started
  when: res.stdout == 'inactive'
  tags:
    - toto

- name: Check for apache status
  service_facts:
- debug:
    var: ansible_facts.services.apache2.state
  tags:
    - toto2

$ ansible-playbook status.yaml -i hosts --tags="toto,toto2"


PLAY [nodeOne] ***************************************************************************
TASK [Start if Service Apache is stopped] ************************************************
changed: [nodeOne]
TASK [Start Apache because service was stopped] ******************************************
    skipping: [nodeOne]
TASK [debug] *****************************************************************************
   ok: [nodeOne] => {
      "ansible_facts.services.apache2.state": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
}
```

At the end of the script, I don't get the output of apache status.

Comment: Depending on the distribution you're on (or running this against) the service name might not be what you think it is ... have you tried looking at `ansible_facts.services` to see if `apache2` features as such?

Comment: From Review: Please describe a bit more what you are trying to achieve. As it is described now, it is very hard to understand what exactly you are asking for.

Comment: sorry, I mean when I execute the script, I got "ansible_facts.services.apache2.state": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!" and I whant to get apache is running or soppedn, not not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Q: "The variable stored in the register is empty."

A: A tag is missing in the task `service_facts`. As a result, this task is skipped and `ansible_facts.services` is not defined. Fix it for example

```
- name: Check for apache status
  service_facts:
  tags: toto2
```

---

Notes

1) With a single tag only it's not necessary to declare a list with one tag.

2) The concept of [Idempotency](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/glossary.html) makes the condition redundant.

> An operation is idempotent if the result of performing it once is exactly the same as the result of performing it repeatedly without any intervening actions.

The module [service](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/service_module.html#service-manage-services) is idempotent. For example the task below

```
- name: Start Apache
  service:
    name: "{{ service_name }}"
    state: started
  tags:
    - toto
```

will make any changes only if the *service* has not been `started` yet. The result of the task will be a started service. Once the *service* is `started` the task will report `[ok]` and not touch the *service*. In this respect, it does not matter what was the previous *state* of the *service* i.e. **there is no reason to run the task conditionally**.

3) The module [service_facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/service_facts_module.html#service-facts-return-service-state-information-as-fact-data) works as expected. For example

```
- service_facts:
- debug:
    var: ansible_facts.services.apache2.state
```

gives

```
"ansible_facts.services.apache2.state": "running"
```

Comment: thank ou for you answer, I understant what you want to tell me, but it not solved my problem

Comment: I mean when I execute the script, I got "ansible_facts.services.apache2.state": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!" and I whant to get apache is running or soppedn, not not defined, the probleme is I want to execute tags

Comment: I found the problem. A tag is missing in the `service_facts`. I hadn't seen it either.